# Variable container name inside html

Tags: html, django

Hi I am trying to use a for loop to assign a chart to a variable container name...please see below.

I have it container0 fixed for now but would like it to evaluate to container0, container1, container2 etc...[image]

[image]
[image: MoNnO.png]

Comment: Can you post the full source(as text, not image) necessary to reproduce your problem and explain exactly what should happen? And which library is the backend using?

Comment: I just added more details

Comment: Also please add suitable tags to your question. HTML doesn't have for loops, but you're clearly using some kind of programming language to generate your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your templatetag instead of what you have currently.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(indexable, i):
return indexable[i]
```

I don't believe that you can use Python's key argument when iterating through forloops in Django. Instead, you must refer to the iteration of the for loop like so.

```
{{ charts|index:forloop.counter0 }}
```